# How can we access to original input message after unmarshal in apache camel

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I am getting an input json string from a queue to my camel route, I need to unmarshal it to get a java object. After unmarshal I can't access my original message via Exchange object in process. If anyone faced the same issue and found solution, could you please answer this.

I tried to unmarshal a json string to java object from incoming camel route. I wan to get access to original input message after unmarshal.

Comment: Forgot to add this thing. My input message is huge about 2000 lines of json string. So I can't do unmarshal and marshal again.

Comment: Question is, why would you need an access to the JSON?

Comment: json string is input to my app from a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the original body to an exchange property. Marshal by default replaces the message body but you can use exchange properties to store values for later use in the route.

```java
from("jms:queue:example")
    .routeId("receiveExampleMessage")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .setProperty("originalBody", body())
    .unmarshal(exampleDataFormat)
    // Usage:
    // Log original body
    .log("original body ${exchangeProperty.originalBody}")
    // Use exchange property with plain java
    .process(ex -> {
        String originalBody = ex.getProperty("originalBody", 
            String.class);
    })
    // Set property value back to body
    .setBody().exchangeProperty("originalBody")
;
```